# Devise: Why doesn't my logout link work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

the problem: In a nutshell, when I try to install a logout link to my app it fails to work. Here's as much context as I can think to put here (if you want anything else, please poke me)...

I've got this in a haml view:

```
= link_to("Logout", destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete)
```

It generates this in the view:

```
<a href="/users/sign_out" data-method="delete" rel="nofollow">Logout</a>
```

I verified that in my config/initializers/devise.rb I have this setting uncommented and correct:

```
config.sign_out_via = :delete
```

I validated the following route:

```
destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format) {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"devise/sessions"}
```

I also have this bit of trickery in my routes.rb, and I suspect this is related to my issue:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => {:sessions => "devise/sessions", :registrations => "users"}
resources :users
```

This last bit is because I want to manage (edit, create and delete) users in my own controller.

The error message I'm getting is as follows:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in UsersController#show

Couldn't find User with ID=sign_out
Rails.root: /home/jaydel/projects/mbsquared-projects/Wilson-Goldrick

app/controllers/users_controller.rb:16:in `show'
```

In my server logs I see this for the request:

```
Started GET "/users/sign_out" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-08-04 13:08:51 -0500
  Processing by UsersController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"sign_out"}
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The problem lies in the fact that in your logs the signout request is a GET request.

```
Started GET "/users/sign_out"
```

But the signout route is a DELETE

```
destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)
```

The reason why you are getting the exception is that is it getting confused with one of the routes created by `resources :users` which would be something like

```
edit_user GET /users/(:id)(.:format) {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"users"}
```

Basically 'sign_out' is being mistaken as a id.

I'm not sure why the delete link is not going through as a DELETE request. Though changing

```
config.sign_out_via = :delete
```

to be `:get` might solve the problem.

Comment: this is NOT a good idea. you are enabling a CSRF attack. POST and DELETE should be used when there is a state change. Make sure you have `jquery_ujs.js` included in your layout

Comment: As Tombart said, this is not a Restful way fix this. POST or DELETE should be used when changing state.

Comment: yeah, I read his answer as "it should be delete, not get, but if you insist on doing it as get, this might work". I changed it to delete and the world was a happier place.

Comment: As soon as one of your user uses a browser which prefetches links (which are GET requests) the user's browser will sign out the user automatically.

Answer (score 86):

The correct way to fix this, REST-wise, would be to change your logout links to use the DELETE method.  It's a very easy fix, changing this:

```
link_to "Log out", destroy_user_session_path
```

to this:

```
link_to "Log out", destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete
```

Answer (score 33):

I had the same problem with rails 3.2 when I deleted from `application.js` this line:

```
//= require jquery_ujs
```

So, I think you have to insert this line in your `application.js` if you haven't it there.

PS. This behavior means that rails adapter for `jquery` doesn't function. So you should make sure if it is loaded in your html in browser. You should test it in development mode because you will have compressed js in production and it will be very difficult to find something there.

Comment: thanks a lot for this post and the solution. I had spent at least 10h on this exact problem, and I had absolutely no clue where it was coming from (this was the issue, and the error was not helpful)!!

Comment: Not just //= require jquery_ujs but //= require jquery too

Comment: Ahhh - I just added a bootstrap theme that wiped the reference to jquery_ujs, nice answer, thanks.

Answer (score 7):

You need both
`link_to "Log out", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete`

&& these included in application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
```

. Obviously, don't forget to add this to Gemfile if for some reason it is not there.

`gem 'jquery-rails'`

Answer (score 7):

I've tried all the solutions mentioned here but the true solution to this issue is the following :

```
<%= link_to "Sign Out", destroy_user_session_path, 'data-turbo-method': :delete%>
```

It works if it doesn't just refresh or restart the server.

Comment: The is how you must now do it with a new Rails 7 app out-of-the-box

Answer (score 4):

This is an old question but the accepted answer is not the proper way to solve this issue (although it is a good diagnosis of the problem).

When I ran into this today my routes file appeared as:

```
  root :to => 'welcome#index' 

  resources :users    
  devise_for :users
```

As mentioned by Olives the resources statement is simply causing /users/anything to trip up.  I simply needed to reverse the ordering of my routes...

```
 root :to => 'welcome#index' 

  devise_for :users
  resources :users
```

Answer (score 4):

jQuery is required in order to perform the request with DELETE. Make sure you didn't drop it from your application.js.

Comment: That's not true: Rails enables DELETE-like requests by adding a hidden `_method` input. It is possible to log out with a form and no JavaScript. See my answer for how to use it.

Answer (score 4):

Since the OP mentioned devise and this problem also happened to me, I just wanted to chime in. @Ross Allen had the correct answer when you don't want to use jQuery_ujs. Rails provides a couple of helpers to solve this without jQuery.

This is Ross's answer but using Devise's current_user model:

```
<%= form_for(current_user,
    url: destroy_user_session_path, html: { method: :delete }) do |f| %>
    <%= f.submit "Log out" %>
<% end %>
```

Or the more succinct [button_to](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to) helper that creates a similar form:

```
<%= button_to "Log out", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %>
```

Comment: This and adding in rails-ujs solved this problem for me. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2):

You also have to check, is `resources :users` under `devise_for :users` and is the link method delete

```
link_to "Logout", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete
```

if both are right, your logout button should work

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question, but I wanted a way that required no JavaScript. Rails enables "DELETE" like requests with a hidden input that sets `method` to `delete`. Use a real `<form>`, and let Rails generate the necessary hidden inputs:

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name,
    url: destroy_user_session_path, html: { method: :delete }) do |f| %>
  <%= f.submit "Log out" %>
<% end %>
```

the above generates something like:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/users/sign_out" method="post">
  <div style="display:none">
    <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓">
    <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="delete">
    <input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="1234">
  </div>
  <input name="commit" type="submit" value="Log out">
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

I've checked all this solutions, but no one has worked for me. Finally I found that in header I deleted two lines including application tags and csrf meta

So, If someone have this problem with no sollution at this point - check if you have in header of the page (HAML notation)

```
= javascript_include_tag 'application'
= csrf_meta_tags
```

Comment: For me it was the line `= csrf_meta_tags` that fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had to go about this in a different manner as my application.rb had:

```
<%= link_to "Sign out", destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete %>
```

and was still failing. It turns out I needed to set `config.serve_static_assets = true` in /environment/development, test and production.rb. [This link](http://rorguide.blogspot.com/2011/05/routing-error-when-running-rails-3.html) was what helped me figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that it's more restful to use the http DELETE method, I like to create a simple endpoint to destroy a user session with a GET method.

by adding this to config/routes.rb

```
devise_scope :user do
  get '/logout',  :to => 'sessions#destroy'
end
```

Answer (score 1):

If your are also having more than one jquery sources in your rails app you need to use the default one specified in the Gemfile

make sure in your Gemfile you have this

```
gem 'jquery-rails'
```

and in your assets you do not have any other JQuery source files.

in my case I had a second JQuery file other than the default as declared in the Gemfile so it caused conflicts.

if you previously had those source, be sure to precompile assets again if you had previously done so

Comment: Good catch! This was my issue

Answer (score 0):

If you're finding this problem in production and you're using the asset pipeline, you often need to:

`rake assets:clobber` in order to clear out your public assets. Then `rake assets:precompile` before committing and pushing your code (unless your push also precompiles, aka Heroku).

Answer (score 0):

the reason may be in the wrong order connection `bootstrap-sprockets`

the correct order:

```
// app/assets/javascripts/application.js

...

//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require_tree .
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by [Tombart](https://stackoverflow.com/users/334831/tombart) above, the answer for me was putting back the rails-ujs call in my application.js file.

```
//= require rails-ujs
//= require turbolinks
```

I had initially removed them to stop errors from having my scripts in the footer be re-evaluated. My workaround was to create a footer.js compile file with the resources I wanted in the footer.

```
//= require jquery-3.2.1.min
//= require jquery-ui-1.12.1.min
//= require materialize
//= require init
```

Then in my /initializers/assets.rb file adding a precompile

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( footer.js )
```

Then you can call the following in your layout/application.html.erb file.

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'footer' %>
```

I keep the application line in my header, and added my new "footer" call before the end of my body tag.

Answer (score 0):

1) I feel u may need to install below gem, the request with method: :delete will work else it may go as get

https://github.com/rails/jquery-rails

2) Add this two below lines in application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Stop the server
```

```
yarn add  "@rails/ujs"
yarn add turbolinks
yarn add @rails/activestorage
```

```
My application.js
```

```
import Rails from "@rails/ujs"
import Turbolinks from "turbolinks"
import * as ActiveStorage from "@rails/activestorage"
import "channels"

Rails.start()
Turbolinks.start()
ActiveStorage.start()
```

```
Start the server
```